# phpMyAdmin not exporting database structures according to foreign keys

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a list of tables in MySQL with foreign key constraints. While exporting, all tables along with views, functions and procedures are exported in alphabetical orders.

As I import thus exported SQL, I am stuck with the error that "Foreign key constraints table not found" though the structure of required table is below in listing.  I want to export them in order so that they maintain every references in structure.

How could it be done using MySQL?

Comment: Export one table at a time, so you can import them separately and make sure you load the key tables before the tables with the foreign keys pointing to them.

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible to export tables in the order that respects "foreign keys", unless you export the tables individually. Then import the tables from the individual export in the order you want. (Note that its possible for a database to contain circular foreign key references, where there's no order that the tables would be in "foreign key" order.)

---

(As an answer to a somewhat different question...)

The workaround for the import error is to *disable* enforcement of foreign keys for the duration of the import process. Setting the `foreign_key_checks` variable to 0 disables enforcement of foreign keys; to re-enable, set the variable to 1.

For example:

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0; 

-- import tables
create table ... 
insert into ...
create table ... 
insert into ...

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```